# How do I construct a Django form that has a ModelChoiceField?

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to write a test for my form which uses a custom ModelChoiceField:

```
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField
class CycleModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, cycle):
        return str(cycle.begin_date)
```

Whatever the user selects in this field needs to be passed into 2 other fields (DateField and radio ChoiceField) by overriding the `clean()` method. That's complicated logic that I need to test.

So here's what I've tried in my test so far:

```
self.client.login(username='user', password='1234')
response = self.client.get(reverse('my_form'), follow=True)
cyc = list(CycleDate.objects.all())[0]
form_data = {'type_of_input': '0', 'cycle': cyc,'usage_type': 'E',}
form = EnergyUsageForm(data=form_data, user=response.context['user'])
```

But the `form.is_valid()` returns false and `form.errors` says:

```
{'cycle': [u'Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}
```

There must be something wrong with my form construction. `'cycle': cyc` clearly isn't working as intended. I've also tried `'cycle': '0'` and `'cycle': '1'`.

What is the correct way to construct a form like this?

**EDIT:**
I should explain what the available choices are. There's only one CycleDate in the database and only one choice. After running the lines of my test in the shell, I typed `form.fields['cycle'].choices.choice(cyc)` which returns `(1, '2015-05-01')`. The strange thing is that `form.fields['cycle'].queryset` returns `[]`. Maybe the issue is related to that?

**EDIT2:**
Here's my form with that complicated (read: messy and terrible and shameful) clean method:

```
class EnergyUsageForm(forms.Form):
    # Override init so that we can pass the user as a parameter.
    # Then put the cycle form inside init so that it can access the current user variable
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(EnergyUsageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Get the last 12 cycle dates for the current user
        td = datetime.date.today
        cycle_dates = CycleDate.objects.filter(cycle_ref=Account.objects.get(holder__user=user).cycle,
                                               begin_date__lte=td).order_by('begin_date')
        self.fields['cycle'] = CycleModelChoiceField(queryset = cycle_dates,
                                                      required = False,
                                                      widget = forms.Select(attrs={"onChange":'changeCalendar()'}),
                                                      label = "Choose a billing cycle")


    type_of_input = forms.ChoiceField(required=False,
                                    widget=forms.Select(attrs={"onChange": "switchInput()"}),
                                    choices=INPUT,
                                    initial='0',
                                    label="Choose a way to display usage", )

    end_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=
                                {
                                    'class':'datepicker'
                                }), 
                                label="Choose start date",
                                help_text='Choose a beginning date for displaying usage',
                                required=True,
                                initial=datetime.date.today,)

    period = forms.ChoiceField(required=True,
                                widget=forms.RadioSelect, 
                                choices=DISPLAY_PERIOD, 
                                initial='01',
                                label="Choose period to display",)

    usage_type = forms.ChoiceField(required=True,
                                widget=forms.RadioSelect,
                                choices=USAGE_TYPE,
                                initial='E',
                                label="Choose type of usage to display",)

    def clean_end_date(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['end_date']

        if datetime.date.today() < data:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Don't choose a future date")
        # Always return the cleaned data, whether you have changed it or
        # not.
        return data

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(EnergyUsageForm, self).clean()
        selection = cleaned_data['type_of_input']
        # Check if the user wants to use cycle_dates instead
        if selection == '0':
            # Set the end_date and period
            cleaned_data['end_date'] = cleaned_data['cycle'].begin_date #MUST BE CHANGED TO END_DATE LATER
            cleaned_data['period'] = cleaned_data['cycle'].duration
        return cleaned_data
```

**EDIT3**
Fixed a typo in my test, and also here's my test's setUp method:

```
client = Client()
    def setUp(self):
        user = User.objects.create_user(username = 'user', password = '1234')
        user.save()
        profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user = user)
        profile.save()
        account = Account(number=1, first_name='test',
                          last_name='User',
                          active=True,
                          holder=profile,
                          holder_verification_key=1)

        account.save()

        the_cycle = Cycle.objects.create(name = 'test cycle')
        the_cycle.save()
        cd = CycleDate.objects.create(begin_date = datetime.date(2015, 5, 1),
                                 end_date = datetime.date.today(),
                                 cycle_ref = the_cycle)
        cd.save()
```

**EDIT4:**
In addition to all this mess, I'm now getting `KeyError: 'cycle'` whenever I call `form.is_valid()`. Probably due to the clean() method trying to access cleaned_data['cycle'] when the cycle field has an invalid selection.

Comment: try `forms.Select` intead of ModelChoiceField

Comment: Either way, use `Cycle.objects.first()` instead of evaluating the queryset with the call to `list`

Comment: Please show your form definition, including that "complicated" clean logic.

Comment: Also, what about `'cycle': cyc.id`?

Comment: @trantu I used that initially, but that complicated clean() method forces me to use ModelChoiceField

Comment: @DanielRoseman cyc.id returns 1, and constructing the form with cyc.id still tells me to select a valid choice

Comment: @DanielRoseman I added the code for the form. Sorry I didn't have it to begin with. Maybe the problem could lie in that overridden __init__ method?

Comment: I see that the query which populates that field depends on the user. Are you sure that your Cycle object is correctly related to the user you are passing in?

Comment: It's actually a CycleDate, not a Cycle. I made a typo in my test, but the error still persists. I think I did correctly create the cycle and cycledate, however. I edited in my setUp method for my test.

Comment: As I mentioned, you haven't associated your Cycle object with a user so the query returns no values.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I copy/pasted the setup from a different method that didn't need to associate Accounts with Cycles. With the setup fixed, I did have to use your suggestion of cyc.id. Thanks so much for your help and patience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by DanielRoseman, the answer is to use the id of the instance.

So the correct way to construct a form with a ModelChoiceField is as follows:

```
my_instance = MyModelName.objects.get(whatever instance you need)
form_data = {'my_regular_choice_field': '0', 'my_model_choice_field': my_instance.id}
form = MyFormName(data=form_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
self.client.login(username='user', password='1234')
response = self.client.get(reverse('my_form'), follow=True)
cyc = list(CycleDate.objects.all())[0]
form_data = {'type_of_input': '0', 'cycle': cyc,'usage_type': 'E',}
form = EnergyUsageForm(data=form_data, user=response.context['user'])
```

especially line

```
cyc = list(CycleDate.objects.all())[0]
```

- first you get iterator of all CycleDates (ok, more or less ok...)
- then you read everything to memory (why!)
- and lastly.. you select first list element (of course, you will get exception if list is empty...)

why not:

```
cyc = CycleDate.objects.first()
if cyc:
    # cycle is a ModelChoice - in html it stores primary key!
    form_data = {'type_of_input': '0', 'cycle': cyc.pk, 'usage_type': 'E'}
    form = EnergyUsageForm(data=form_data, user=response.context['user'])
```

EnergyUsageForm's init:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    super(EnergyUsageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # today is a function!
    td = datetime.date.today()
    account = Account.objects.get(holder__user=user)
    cycle_dates = CycleDate.objects.filter(cycle_ref=account.cycle,
                                           begin_date__lte=td)
                                   .order_by('begin_date')

    self.fields['cycle'] = CycleModelChoiceField(queryset=cycle_dates,
                                                 required=False,
                                                 widget=forms.Select(attrs={"onChange":'changeCalendar()'}),
                                                 label = "Choose a billing cycle")
```